# Creating a fake command, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: reactiveui

I've implemented a login dialog for an application. When the "login" button is clicked, the UI is disabled and a spinner is shown while the login happens. Also, if the user has previously logged in, the app can use a saved token to automatically log in again.

To implement this, I have created two commands. One command for the user-initiated login, and one command for the automatic login. This is so I can observe the IsExecuting Observable for both commands, something like this

```
_isExecuting = this.WhenAnyObservable(
    x => x.CmdLogin.IsExecuting,
    x => x.CmdAutoLogin.IsExecuting)
.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsExecuting);
```

The IsExecuting viewmodel property is then bound to the Isnabled property of the view. This is working and the UI behaves perfectly, but it feels very unclean having two commands. Also, I am triggering the automatic login in the viewmodel like so:

```
this.WhenActivated((Action<IDisposable> disposer) =>
{
    (CmdAutoLogin as System.Windows.Input.ICommand).Execute(null);
});
```

My question is, what is a cleaner way to do this? Can I do this without having two commands? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cast to ICommand.

Import this namespace:

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
```

Then just await a command:

```
await CmdAutoLogin.Execute();
```

Or use the Adrian Romero way:

```
Observable.Return(Unit.Default).InvokeCommand();
```

Comment: I don't seem to have that Execute() extension method - is that in another nuget package or a different version of reactiveui? I am using 8.2.1. It looks handy though!

Comment: I guess you are declaring your commands like "public ReactiveCommand CmdLogin {get; private set;}". You need to change declaration to: "public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> CmdLogin {get; private set;}".

Comment: Actually it seems in my case that Execute() does not trigger the IsExecuting observable, but using Adrian's way does. Interesting.

Comment: I think cmdAutoLogin.Execute() invokes ICommand method, whereas InvokeCommand acts on ReactiveCommandBase.Execute

Comment: I don't think so, I did a test and it works fine, IsExecuting is changing. Also, importing System.Reactive.Linq just makes IObservable awaitable.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach its ok, I am on a similiar situation and I have AutoLogin and Login on separate commands, If you think about it, auto login and login are different things, at least to me. The only thing I'd do different would be to put 
*CmdAutoLogin* execution on the view and not in de view model:

```
this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {
            Observable.Return(Unit.Default).InvokeCommand(ViewModel.CmdAutoLogin);
        });
```

Comment: Good idea, it makes the call simpler too because now I don't need to explicitly specify the parameter type. Cheers!

Comment: Why not: this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.CmdAutoLogin).SelectMany(cmd => cmd.Execute).Subscribe() ? from the view. https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/automatic-execution